# Linq to simple foreach cicles

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have the following code and need to convert it to simple statements (remove using of linq).

Can anybody help?

```
  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            list.Add(element);
        }

        var enumerable = elements as IList<T> ?? list;

        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
            enumerable.SelectMany((e, i) =>
                    enumerable.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat<T>(c)));
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem are you facing?

Comment: Everything is working, but when I call this function in SQL CLR ASSEMBLY it returns null reference exception. I want to remove using linq and remove reference of System.Core from my assembly. I think the problem in using System.Core in SQL CLR ASSEMBLY

Comment: Linq or no Linq, that `foreach` loop will cause a `NullReferenceException` if `elements` is `null`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet is right. Test your code with null values and see what happens. Best case: write UnitTests for it. If it then throws the same exceptions in production, you'll know why.

Comment: Agreed, @PieterWitvoet is right. This can be avoided by casting, `elements as IList<T>` earlier in the method and only create a new `List<T>` if the cast is `null`.  This also prevents the performance issue of creating a new `List<T>` on each recursion.  Additional unnecessary looping can be avoided by returning early when `k > enumerable.Count` or `k = enumerable.Count`.

Comment: the code works when I call it from unit test, but when I call it from sql clr assembly it faults (with the same parameters)

Comment: the list is not null, I've checked it already

Answer (score 1):

I've finally resolved the problem. I used udf clr function that reads data from database without using  **[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]** attributes, and passed the result to Combination functions. As a result the parameter of function was null and it throwed exception.